# Email to case attachments from closed to open cases

Tags: administration, email2case

I am facing one problem related to email to case feature. Please see below points to understand my issue:

- One Closed case is sitting with one attachment.
- Customer sends another email on the closed case with an attachment.
- New open case is created with the new attachment but the old attachment doesn't come through in the new case.
- We are using a visual flow for this feature i don't see any error in the flow.
  Is there anything which i am missing here from the settings.?

Thanks
Rohan

Comment: Hello Rohan, could you please share what have you attempted and where you are struggling? I would ask myself what is the execution flow and what is missing to achieve the goal.

Comment: Hi Jef
you want me to share the flow design or just info. what things are working or what not.?

Comment: Hello Rohan - The flow design might be too much, but if it helps to explain the context it will be appreciated. Share what you feel could explain what is working, what you attempted to perform to overcome the challenge and where you got stuck.